# Flutter alerts (multiple flutter plugins) showing alert 1, then for the 2nd alert it shows alert 1 & 2, etc

Tags: flutter, dart

Really odd behavior, I'm sure someone knows the reason...

I have tried with these plugins:
rflutter_alert
alert
cool_alert

This is also happening with the standard flutter method for alerts, using showDialog and AlertDialog

The behavior is that when the first alert when running the app shows it is normal, but when a second alert is triggered after the first is dismissed, it shows both alerts (#1 and #2), and when a third alert is triggered it shows #1, #2, and #3..etc

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:status_alert/status_alert.dart';
import 'package:rflutter_alert/rflutter_alert.dart';

// Show error alert
void ErrorMessage(BuildContext context, String error) {
  Alert(context: context, title: "Error", desc: error).show();
}
```

Here is where I call this function in my code:

```
// Initialize the usb serial connection, send a ping message to verify brefx connectivity.
  // Executes every 15 seconds unless data collection is started.
  void InitConnection() async {
    print("*** INIT CONNECTION RUNNING...");
    setState(() {
      initLoading = true;
      connectionStatus = false;
      usbConnected = true;
    });
    iTimer = Timer(Duration(milliseconds: 10000), InitGuarantor);
    // USB Serial
    List<UsbDevice> devices = await UsbSerial.listDevices();
    if (devices.length == 0) {
      ErrorMessage(context, "No device found");
      setState(() {
        connectionStatus = false;
        initLoading = false;
        usbConnected = false;
      });
      iTimer.cancel();
      return;
    }
    port = await devices[0].create();

    bool? openResult = await port?.open();
    // Check for open connection
    if ( !openResult! ) {
      print("Failed to open");
      openResult = await port?.open();
      if ( !openResult! ) {
        print("Failed to open");
        ErrorMessage(context, "Unable to connect");
        setState(() {
          connectionStatus = false;
          listenWait = false;
          listenEnabled = false;
          initLoading = false;
          usbConnected = false;
        });
        iTimer.cancel();
        return;
      }
    }

    await port?.setDTR(true);
    await port?.setRTS(true);

    port?.setPortParameters(bautRate, UsbPort.DATABITS_8,
        UsbPort.STOPBITS_1, UsbPort.PARITY_NONE);

    // Listen for a detached USB cable
    usbListener = UsbSerial.usbEventStream?.listen((UsbEvent msg) {
      print(msg);
      if (msg.event == UsbEvent.ACTION_USB_ATTACHED) {
        print("USB CONNECTED");
      }
      if (msg.event == UsbEvent.ACTION_USB_DETACHED) {
        ErrorMessage(context, "Lost connection");
        setState(() {
          connectionStatus = false;
          listenWait = false;
          listenEnabled = false;
          usbConnected = false;
        });
        try {
          iTimer.cancel();
        } catch(e) {
          print(e);
        }
        ResetFields();
      }
    });
```

flutter doctor -v

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.10.5, on macOS 12.5.1 21G83 darwin-arm, locale
    en-US)
    • Flutter version 2.10.5 at /Users/kylebessemer/development/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 5464c5bac7 (4 months ago), 2022-04-18 09:55:37 -0700
    • Engine revision 57d3bac3dd
    • Dart version 2.16.2
    • DevTools version 2.9.2

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/kylebessemer/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-32, build-tools 32.0.0
    • ANDROID_SDK_ROOT = /Users/kylebessemer/Library/Android/sdk
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android
      Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
      11.0.12+0-b1504.28-7817840)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.4.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • CocoaPods version 1.11.3

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
      11.0.12+0-b1504.28-7817840)

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2021.3.1)
    • IntelliJ at /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart

[✓] VS Code (version 1.63.2)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension can be installed from:
       https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • SM G990U1 (mobile) • adb-R5CT61F27SZ-PRSWJu._adb-tls-connect._tcp. •
      android-arm64  • Android 12 (API 31)
    • Chrome (web)       • chrome                                        •
      web-javascript • Google Chrome 104.0.5112.101
    ! Error: iPad (3) is not connected. Xcode will continue when iPad (3) is
      connected. (code -13)
    ! Error: iPhone 13 Pro Max is not connected. Xcode will continue when iPhone
      13 Pro Max is connected. (code -13)

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

• No issues found!
```

Not sure if related but I am having to use sdk version 30 for this app

Comment: ccan you post the code where you call  the function?

Comment: I posted, thanks for your interest